# MySQL, generate a random 42 character string for a column

Tags: mysql, database, string, random

I need to generate a 42 character string for a column for each row in my table ... it's used as a password recovery string. It must be 42 characters long and would be helpful if it was unique...

If the user forgets the password, generate a string. Upon an email, generating a string of "abc123" I presume it does the following: "SELECT FROM users WHERE recovery_string="abc123"

Comment: What do you mean it's "*used as a password recovery string*"?  Can you elaborate?  Suggest you read [The definitive guide to form based website authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/a/477578), especially "**PART IV: Forgotten Password Functionality**".

Comment: Why exactly 42 characters?

Comment: He means if the user forgets the password, generate a string. Upon an email, generating a string of "abc123" I presume it does the following: "SELECT FROM users WHERE recovery_string="abc123" - Now reset their password...

Comment: Yes, exactly ... thank you anonymous.

Comment: @Anonymous2011: That's what I had feared, but gave the OP the benefit of the doubt.  As explained in the article to which I have linked, doing that would be **a very bad idea**.

Comment: @dcolumbus I have provided you with sufficient code, if you wish to use it.  - Could you elaborate why that's a bad idea eggyal? As 9/10 services that integrate a password reset function, works on this principle: Generating a random string, and emailing, associating that string with the account...I'm not saying you are wrong, I'm merely curious.

Comment: @Anonymous2011: If you took the time to read the article to which I linked, you'd understand that a password reset token is a *password equivalent* and must be salted-hashed just like a password.  Storing plaintext tokens in the database is as insecure as storing plaintext passwords in the database.

Comment: @eggyal, I missed that comment, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see this code, I have generated it just for this question.

It's probably not the best way of doing it I'm sure, but this will work:

Edit: Turned into a function, so you can choose which length. Old code is below.

New code:

```
    <?php
function GenerateRecoveryString($length)
{
    $time=time();
    $az="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    //$time and $az is just random stuff to generate a hash out of. 
    $output = md5($time.$az);//The soon to be 42 char string.
    while(strlen($output)<$length)
    {
        $output.=md5($time.$az);//md5 only creates 32 bit strings - Lets create one that's 42 chars.
    }
    $output = substr($output, "0",$length);//The above example created 64 bit string - We need to cut it down.
    str_shuffle($az);//Randomize the string above, to ensure a different output next time.
    echo $output.' Length:'.strlen($output);
    }
    echo GenerateRecoveryString("42");
?>
```

---

```
<?php
$time=time();
$az="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
//$time and $az is just random stuff to generate a hash out of. 
$output = md5($time.$az);//The soon to be 42 char string.
while(strlen($output)<"42")
{
    $output.=md5($time.$az);//md5 only creates 32 bit strings - Lets create one that's 42 chars.
}
$output = substr($output, "0","42");//The above example created 64 bit string - We need to cut it down.
str_shuffle($az);//Randomize the string above, to ensure a different output next time.
echo $output.' Length:'.strlen($output);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this on MySQL side you can try to use `SHA1()` by passing the result of concatenation of several columns that is unique. For example `id`, `username` an `date` when an account was created. It will procude you a unique string 40 characters in length.

```
UPDATE users 
   SET recovery_hash = SHA1(CONCAT(id, username, created));
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0090/1)** demo